# Nautilus - Connect to Server option not visible

Tags: ssh, nautilus, connection, sftp

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. I read that the file manager Nautilus can be used to transfer files to and from remote servers. I also read that one can do this by selecting "Connect to Server" from the File menu of Nautilus.

For some reason I do not see "Connect to Server". I see:

- New Window
- Sidebar
- Keyboard Shortcuts
- Help
- About

and a few other things.

What am I doing incorrectly?

EDIT: 
The possible duplicate is not the same issue, but through it I was able to find the solution:

The Connect button is not in the File menu, but rather at the bottom of the Nautilus window as an Input field: Connect to Server [Enter server address..]. Select "+ Other Locations" and the field will appear on the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should:

1. Enable leftside bar with <kbd>F9</kbd> (skip this step if it is already enabled).
2. Click on *Other locations*
3. Find *Connect to Server* in the buttom of the window:

   [image: Connect to Server]
4. Enter address with protocol - one from

   - AppleTalk - `afp://`;
   - File Transfer Protocol - `ftp://` or `ftps://`;
   - Network File System - `nfs://`;
   - Samba - `smb://`;
   - SSH File Transfer Protocol - `sftp://` or `ssh://`;
   - WebDAV - `dav://` or `davs://`.

   Note: you can specify *username* directly by `sftp://username@server` or wait for authentication window to pop up after next step.
5. Click *Connect*

---

Simpler method is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to access the address bar and then type the address here and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.